# Django FOREIGN KEY constraint failure in pre_delete

Tags: python, django, database

I've read quite a few related questions, since this is a beginner DB mistake, but for some reason I can't apply the answers to my situation.

I have the following `Event` model, which contains a foreign key to a `Machine` model describing the originator of an event,

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(
        Machine,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        help_text='The machine this event originated from, or NULL if it has been deleted.')

    CATEGORY_MACHINE_CREATED = 'machine-created'
    CATEGORY_MACHINE_UPDATED = 'machine-updated'
    CATEGORY_MACHINE_REMOVED = 'machine-removed'

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (CATEGORY_MACHINE_CREATED, 'Machine has been created'),
        (CATEGORY_MACHINE_UPDATED, 'Machine has been updated'),
        (CATEGORY_MACHINE_REMOVED, 'Machine has been removed'),
    )

    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,
        help_text='The category of the event.')
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        help_text='The time this event was created.')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<Event id={self.id} machine={self.machine} category={self.category}>"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

I use signals to generate events around the lifetime of `Machine` models,

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Machine)
def machine_change_callback(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        logger.warning("CREATED %s %s %s" % (sender, instance, kwargs))
        return Event.objects.create(
            category=Event.CATEGORY_MACHINE_CREATED,
            machine=instance)
    else:
        logger.warning("UPDATED %s %s %s" % (sender, instance, kwargs))
        return Event.objects.create(
            category=Event.CATEGORY_MACHINE_UPDATED,
            machine=instance)


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Machine)
def machine_deleted_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    logger.warning("REMOVED %s %s %s" % (sender, instance, kwargs))
    return Event.objects.create(
        category=Event.CATEGORY_MACHINE_REMOVED,
        machine=instance)
```

Then, the following works as I expect,

```
from infra.models import Machine, Event, PDU

pdu = PDU.objects.create(name="MyPDU", pdu_model='PDU1',
                         url='http://pdu.gateway')

m = Machine.objects.create(base_name="gfx8",
                           mac_address="de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe",
                           ip_address="192.168.0.1",
                           pdu=pdu, pdu_port_id="42")
```

The `machine-created` event fires,

```
>>> Event.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Event: <Event id=1 machine=<Machine: gfx8-1> category=machine-created>>]>
```

And the machine is in the DB,

```
>>> m.pk
1
>>> Machine.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Machine: <Machine: mupuf-gfx8-1>>]>
```

I expect that calling `m.delete()` will first hit my `pre_delete` hook, add a `machine-removed` event referencing the `gfx8-1` machine, and finally delete the first machine and NULL out the machine fields in my two events, but instead I get a FOREIGN_KEY error,

```py
>>> m.delete()
WARNING 2021-02-01 19:07:08,940 /app/infra/signals.py:machine_deleted_callback 64 139860469688128   REMOVED <class 'infra.models.Machine'> <Machine: gfx8-1> {'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7f33cc7342e0>, 'using': 'default'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Why set the machine foreign key in the created Event when you are just going to set it to null?

Comment: That's part of my question, I would like to be able to fetch a deleted event and see what machine was deleted, does that imply I should serialize a machine into a JSONField or something in the Event rather than a foreign key to a Machine?

Comment: Has the `Machine` instance you are deleting in this case been saved to the db? I think that would explain the error

Comment: I agree there is no point saving a foreign key to something you are about to delete. A foreign key just points to another row in your db. But if that row has been deleted, you're obviously not going to get any info that way. None-the-less, it is interesting question as to why this error occurs.

Comment: A potential solution is to not actually delete the `Machine` instance, rather add a boolean field named "active" or "archived" and set this flag to `True`. This way the foreign key can be non-nullable and you can then always access the data as it's never deleted

Comment: As for why the error occurs, it's may be to do with the way transactions are handled by sqlite

Comment: Thank you, I wondered about adding a "deleted flag", wasn't sure if that's a thing you do in DBs :-). I updated my question to confirm that the machine really is in the DB.